# File Encryption with Rijndael

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm making a program to Encrypt Files.I want to have my method for encrypting the files with Rijndael **in a dll**.But when I add it to the dll the command

Application.DoEvents();

does no work.Is there another method for doing the Encryption **with Rijndael without using 
        Application.DoEvents();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Encryption with Rijndael without using Application.DoEvents()

I don't understand why you need this though, but yes, you can do the following:

```
using (System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael rijndael = System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael.Create()) {

    rijndael.GenerateKey();
    // Set your Key 
    // rijndael.Key = key;
    rijndael.GenerateIV();
    // Set your IV
    // rijndael.IV = iv;
    rijndael.BlockSize = 256; // this is what makes it different from AES
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor()) {
        var fileToBeEncrypted = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Path");
        transform.TransformFinalBlock(fileToBeEncrypted, 0, fileToBeEncrypted.Length);
    }
}
```

If your file is large, then this approach would not be very efficient. In that case you'd better make use of stream similar to the following approach:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream inputFs = new System.IO.FileStream("inputPath", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(inputFs, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
        using (System.IO.FileStream outputFs = new System.IO.FileStream("outputPath", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew)) {
            cs.CopyTo(outputFs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set my own Key and IV.

Comment: @NewProgramer: you are welcome, please see the alternate approach as well.

Comment: And.. If i fully understand to decrypt the file replace rijndael.CreateEncryptor() with rijndael.CreateDecryptor() ?

Comment: @NewProgramer: Exactly, so simple as that :)

Comment: Don’t use a block size of 256. Stick with 128, and better yet use AES instead of Rijndael. All AES is Rijndael, but not all Rijndael is AES and only the AES parts are portable.

Comment: @bartonjs: The OP asked for Rijndael and not AES, but why are you suggesting not to use the 256 block size, would you please share what you know (for the sake of information exchange)?

Comment: When the BlockSize is 128 (the default) it’s compatible with AES. When the blocksize is 256 you lose a lot of interoperability. .NET Core only supports the blocksize of 128, for example.